# css sticky element not retaining its parents' properties

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello good people of stack overflow. Please kindly help me look into this issue I have with a CSS sticky property applied to a div not retaining its parents' properties when scrolled on. The situation is like this:

I have a bootstrap navigator wrapped in a col div which is also wrapped in a row div I have applied the sticky property to the row div and used javascript to apply the sticky behavior (as fixed) on scroll to but when the window scrolls to that row, it retains all the elements in the row div and their properties but never the properties of the row div itself which is supposed to render a concrete beauty. Please kindly help look into this. Thanks.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  stickNav()
};

var nav = document.getElementById("navtwksamp");
var sticky = nav.offsetTop;

function stickNav() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    nav.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="navtwksamp">
  <div class="col-12">
    <nav class="">
      <div class="">

        <div style="">...</div>
        <div class="">...</div>

      </div>
      <nav class=""> ... </nav>

    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't yet have enough reputation to attach an image of exactly what I mean but here are links if accessible. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
  height : 200vh;
}

.child {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
  position: sticky; /* important */
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Header</div>
</div>
```

You can use **`position: sticky;`**

please refer,

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

```
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: While that link may be of use, link only answers are not acceptable on Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to provide a working example of using `position: sticky`

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot. I didn't add a background color to the row style. That's why the div (parent) row did not render well. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You missing content above and below the div class named with row therefore you have no height to scroll and you thinking its not working.  just see below code i have reused your code and its working absolutely fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullam</p>
  <div class="row" id="navtwksamp">
    <div class="col-12">
      <nav class="">
        <div class="">

          <div style="">Home</div>
          <div class="">About</div>

        </div>
        <nav class=""> Contact </nav>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {
  stickNav()
};

var nav = document.getElementById("navtwksamp");
var sticky = nav.offsetTop;

function stickNav() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    nav.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do have contents up and above the div. I only shortened with ellipses to ask the question on here. lakshitha has the answer to this. Thanks.